# Setting view formats for custom mimetypes in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, rails-routing

I'm creating a custom mimetype in rails to use with respond_to

`Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :modal`

I want to use this mime type in respond_to like so:

```
respond_to do |format|                                                                                                                                     
  format.html{ render 'index'}                                                                                                                             
  format.modal{ render 'index', :layout => 'bare'}                                                                                      
 end
```

I want this format to basically serve the same views as the .thml format but with a different layout

I'm getting a missing template error

`Missing template support/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:modal], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/remote/app/views",`

its looking for a view named `index.modal.erb`
i currently only have `index.html.erb`

I've tried creating the `index.modal.erb` and it does work but then the layout has the same problem i only have a layout at `bare.html.erb`

I really don't want to duplicate these view files for the different mime types. I'm hoping theres a way to have the custom mime type fall back on to html views that i am missing.

Comment: So far the only functional solution i've found to this is to rename all the views from `view.html.erb` to just `view.erb` that way rails dosn't look for a specific format and just defaults to `view.erb` this is less then ideal in a project with a lot of existing view files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going by your requirement that

> I want this format to basically serve the same views as the .html format but with a different layout

I have a different approach that should work in Rails 3 (tested in Rails 3.2.12). Put the following in your controller:

```
  before_filter do
    @bare= (params[:format] == 'modal')

    if @bare
      params[:format]= 'html'
      request.format= :html
    end
  end

  layout :select_layout

  # standard controller stuff

  # ...
  # Towards bottom of your controller code, 
  private
  def select_layout
    @bare ? 'bare' : nil
  end
```

Summary:

- Change the format back to html.
- Set a variable to indicate that it needs to serve 'bare'
- Tell controller that value of layout will be given by a function. (See 'Choosing Layouts at Runtime' in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)
- No changes needed in any of the respond_to blocks.

This will do exactly what you need, i.e., same action as .html but with a different layout.

Answer (score -2):

What version of Rails are you using? If 3.2, try setting the format explicitly for your modal response:

```
respond_to do |format|                                                                                                                                     
  format.html  { render 'index'}                                                                                                                             
  format.modal { render 'index', :formats => [:html], :layout => 'bare'}                                                                                      
end
```

That should make it render index.html.erb instead of index.modal.erb.

Comment: Unfortunately the project is rails 3.0.11. This solution dosen't seem to work. Was it introduced at a later version?